# Handling selectSingleNode(Xpath) in XML/Soap envelope having elements with same prefix and multiple uri

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, namespaces

I have a Soap packet  with same prefix ns2 for multiple uri: http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestServices, http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestServices.DTO.

When I am trying to set value in XDoc using xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath, oManager).InnerXml , it is giving null because of multiple uri conflict. Is there any way to dynamically hanlde this? I cannot do any changes in xpath as it is coming from different services with different format. My namespace manager code is as follows:

```
public static XmlNamespaceManager getAllNamespaces(XmlDocument xDoc)
        {
            XmlNamespaceManager result = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);

            IDictionary<string, string> localNamespaces = null;
            XPathNavigator xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
            while (xNav.MoveToFollowing(XPathNodeType.Element))
            {
                localNamespaces = xNav.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.Local);
                foreach (var localNamespace in localNamespaces)
                {
                    string prefix = localNamespace.Key;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
                        prefix = "DEFAULT";
                    result.AddNamespace(prefix, localNamespace.Value);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

foreach (Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTreeNode tn in treeView.SelectedNode.Nodes)
   {
      if (tn.Text == r.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
             {
        string xPath = tn.FullPath;
        xPath = "//" + xPath.Replace(@"\", "/").Replace(" ", "");
        if (!(r.Cells[2].Value.ToString().StartsWith("<") && r.Cells[2].Value.ToString().EndsWith(">")) && !(r.Cells[2].Value.ToString().StartsWith("[") && r.Cells[2].Value.ToString().EndsWith("]")))
        {                                                   
            xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath, oManager).InnerXml = r.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            }
         }
   }
```

My soap envelope is as follows:

```
<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <s11:Body>
    <ns1:AccountCreation xmlns:ns1='www.test.com'>
      <ns1:Data>
        <ns2:LoginUser xmlns:ns2='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestServices'>?XXX?</ns2:LoginUser>
        <ns2:UserPassword xmlns:ns2='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestServices'>?XXX?</ns2:UserPassword>
        <ns2:IPAddress xmlns:ns2='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestServices'>?XXX?</ns2:IPAddress>
        <ns2:ProductID xmlns:ns2='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestServices.DTO'>?999?</ns2:ProductID>
        <ns2:BusinessAccountNumber xmlns:ns2='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestServices.DTO'>?999.99?</ns2:BusinessAccountNumber>
        <ns2:StoreName xmlns:ns2='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestServices.DTO'>?XXX?</ns2:StoreName>
        <ns2:Title xmlns:ns2='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestServices.DTO'>?XXX?</ns2:Title>
      </ns1:Data>
    </ns1:AccountCreation>
  </s11:Body>
</s11:Envelope>
```

Comment: `AddNamespace` will handle the duplicates, and the actual value of the prefix in your XPath isn't really important - what namespace it maps to is. It's not really clear what your problem is, can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Charles Thanks for your response. Problem is that I am getting null from selectsinglenode(xpath, nsmanager) method while trying to modify Xpath s11:Envelope\s11:Body\ns1:AccountCreation\ns1:Data\ns2:LoginUser  to set some user input from grid.

Comment: I am using using 'xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath, oManager).InnerXml = some value' to set the xpath value

Comment: I think you're approaching this backwards - you should be defining your namespace manager in *your* code, not filling it based on what is in the document. If you're dependent on the XML for filling it then you'll fail to read any XML node that doesn't have the same prefixes as your XPath expressions (as well as running into issues like this one).

Comment: I cant have a predefined manager as I am getting lot of xdocs like this from multiple services. In fact we are developing a client for testing of webservices.

Comment: If you've predefined your XPath, then why can't your predefine the namespaces that it relies on? Relying on prefixes is very unreliable - you know what the namespaces are in advance, so why not use them?

Comment: Charles, I dont have a predifined Xpath also. All these are generated dynamically. Just for showing an example I have copied that XPath from Quick Watch and pasted here.

Comment: You'll need to show how you're creating them dynamically, then. As ever with questions, a [mcve] will allow people to see exactly what the issue is. You should still be able to do this without using the prefixes defined in the document.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the code . Actually when user clicks on treeview node, details will be displayed in grid. When user click on update in Grid , I have to update in tree view as well as xDoc.Like XML -> Treeview -> Grid and vice versa